# Npm run build React.js

Tags: reactjs

When I run npm run build in any react project that I code, it creates build folder, but when I click index.html file, the browser shows blank page. Why? How can I fix this? Console shows me no errors.
[ac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr8r4.png)

Comment: screenshot https://prnt.sc/t7vi0f

Comment: You need a local server i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test a React build on your local machine, you can follow these simple steps:
Install Node.js: If you haven't already, download and install Node.js on your machine from the official Node.js website.
Clone or download the React project: Clone or download the React project that you want to test to your local machine.
Install dependencies: Open the terminal or command prompt and navigate to the project folder. Run the following command to install all the dependencies:
`npm install`
Build the project: Once all the dependencies are installed, you can build the project by running the following command:
`npm run build`
This command will create a production build of your React app in the "build" folder.
Serve the build: Finally, you can serve the build by running the following command:
`npx serve -s build`
This will serve the build on a local server, and you can view it by opening a web browser and going to http://localhost:5000 (or whichever port the server is running on).
That's it! You can now test your React build on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

React apps built using `create-react-app` will only run when served using http.

You can try `npx http-server` in your build folder and visit [localhost:8080](http://localhost:8080/)

Answer (score 0):

You can make an index.html like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

Actually this is the real way you do it when you build your app for production and want it to serve. The method @aghArdeshir has suggested is for development purpose. Once your build is ready, you can serve it through a local server(like node or xampp) or just test it by opening it in a browser.